# Paypal Express Checkout get shipping address

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I am using Express Checkout do my payment, how cloud i get customer shipping address before `create payment` setup, and get it when shipping address is changed, so i can calculate freight to customer and change total price on right top.

I read this [document](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/show-payment-details/) but not get anything helpful.

[image]

Comment: What are you getting for the response when you hit the `self` link from the create payment response?